Duplicated icons in panel
First, sorry for my english, I'm southamerican.
I have Lubuntu 24.04
Suddenly, probably after some actualization,(not sure),my panel began to duplicate the icons every time I opened one of them. I read an article that say: "it's the status tray plugin", but didn´t say how to find it,nor how to fix it. I'm lost!

Providing a link to a picture of what you're seeing may help us to better understand. I'd likely right-click & Configure Panel, go to widgets tab and ensure you've not duplicated something there.. but what I'd exactly look for will depend on what you're seeing (ie. picture would be useful).

You're right, I'll try to put a screenshot here

No way, how can I upload an image??

How can I upload an image here?

It's easiest to provide a link (you can embed a link into the question which is how its normally achieved).

Sorry guiverc, don´t know how to make a link and my time is reduced because of my teaching job. Will post the question in the main page again, as if was new, and paste a pic in there. Hope you can see it and help me :)

This question is similar to: Every time I open an icon it appears duplicated in my panel. Lubuntu 24.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
